# Increment "sequence" column based on alphabetical order of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, row-number

Assume the following schema:

```
text|sequence
----|--------
Foo |       1
Bar |       2
Baz |       3
```

How would I `UPDATE` the `sequence` column so it incremented starting at 1 with no gaps based on the alphabetical order of the `text` column?

The resulting data would look like:

```
text|sequence
----|--------
Foo |       3
Bar |       1
Baz |       2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE A 
SET A.sequene = B.sequence 
FROM tableA A 
INNER JOIN (SELECT text, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY text) sequence 
            FROM tableA 
           ) AS B ON A.text = B.text
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly for selecting, but what about UPDATE the sequence column with the incremental value?

Comment: That works well! Only catch is if I add a WHERE clause there are gaps in the numbers because it's iterating over rows being skipped. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: No need, turns out if you put the WHERE clause inside the nested select, the increment only applied for the subset of the table that's relevant. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Sequence = A.newSequence
FROM (SELECT Text, Sequence, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sequence) newSequence
            FROM TABLEA) A
```